# JSHint in WebStorm doesn't know protractor command "browser"

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, protractor, webstorm, jshint

I'm trying to make test for AngularJS web page in **WebStorm** (using **Jasmine** and **Protractor** frameworks), I'm using **JHint** for code inspection...

All code is OK except one command: "browser", example of code:

```
describe('Test',function(){
    it('Open page',function(){
        browser.get('https://www.angularjs.org');
        browser.sleep(2000);
    });
});
```

JSHint is still highlighting errors with browser:

> Problem synopsis JSHint: 'browser' is not defined. (W117)
>
> Unresolved function or method sleep() at line 20

**In JHint Environment I have enabled:**

1. Jasmine
2. Node.js

**In JavaScript Libraries I have enabled:**

1. Node.js Core
2. angular-protractor-DefinitelyTyped
3. jasmine-DefinitelyTyped
4. selenium-webdriver-DefinitelyTyped

Does anybody know what do I have to enable or which Library do I have to download to make JSHint understand the "browser" command please?

Comment: Have a similar problem. Interesting observation: it recognizes `driver.sleep(10);` but does not `browser.sleep(10)`.

Comment: next level is browser.driver.sleep(10) which is the correct way according to JSHint

Answer (score 2):

Do you have a .jshintrc file ?

```
{
    "globals": {
        "browser": false,
    },
    "jasmine": true
}
```

You can add browser as a global.

Comment: Yeah, but it doesn't solve anything - browser will be OK, but his methods will still be in error state for JSHint (for example .Sleep()). And this function (browser) is such a fundamental, so I don't understand why JSHint doesn't know it....

Answer (score 1):

JSHint works on per-file basis and doesn't 'see' global variables defined in other files unless they are added to 'global' list. This can be done by either adding the corresponding comments (/* global browser*/) to your files - see http://www.jshint.com/docs/, or by adding variables/functions you'd like to use globally to the 'Predefined' list in WebStorm Preferences -> Languages & Frameworks -> Javascript -> Code Quality Tool -> JSHint -> Predefined (,separated).

Comment: thanks for help.
For now, I have to have "element, by, browser" in Predefined in JSHint... this is still the only option I can find over internet and here... but I solve the problelm with browser, correct way how to sleep it is: *browser.driver.sleep(10)*. But sitll I don't like it, the JSHint doesn't understand these basic functions of Jasmine